# Cannot destructure property 'user' of 'context' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-context

I'm trying to catch some data globally and I see somethingo about creating our own hooks, but for some reason they are not working! I have already create the context file and imported on the component I want to use, but still dosen't working.

**My user context |** `context/user.js`

```js
const { createContext, useState, useContext } = require("react");

const UserContext = createContext();

export default function UserProvider({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);

  return(
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        setUser
      }}
    >
      { children }
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useUser() {
  const context = useContext(UserContext);
  const { user, setUser } = context;
  return { user, setUser };
}
```

**The component who i'm trying to put the state |** `components/header/index.js`

```js
import React from 'react';

// Component Elements (E.g: Images, sounds, videos).
import Logo from '../../images/logo.png';

// Every style of this component.
import { Container } from './styles';

import { useUser } from '../../context/User';

export default function Header() {
  const [user, setUser ] = useUser();

  return (
    <Container>
      <img src={Logo} alt="Logo" />

      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href='/#'>home</a></li>
          <li><a href='https://github.com/llgava/hash-search' target="__blank">open source</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <p>{user.dsID}</p>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

The screenshot of error
[image: The screenshot of error]

Comment: Judging by the code that you provided, it should be working. But some code is not here like where you put provider and if your content is wrapped by provider. Can you provide that also or even better make codesandbox example. Also your `useUser` should return array, not `{user, setUser}`

Comment: @MarioPetrovi, well, what i want to return is a object from the MongoDB: https://imgur.com/a/fLWVZsb

Comment: Ok, but you are destructuring array on the spot where you use `useUser`